# How to make Qlik Sense extensions developed using AngularJS re-render on resize or when the data changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qliksense

I'm a beginner in developing Qlik Sense extensions.

When using plain JavaScipt, I write the rendering logic inside the 'paint' function and it gets executed and the view gets re-rendered, whenever I resize the element or when the data changes on applying filters. Since I'm now using AngularJS, how to achieve this?

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you basically bind to any of the models in Qlik Sense, AngularJS would take care of that without any further do.

Have a look at the following examples:

- http://qliksite.io/tutorials/qliksense-visualization-extensions/part-02/02-The-Angular-Way--Basics/#
- https://github.com/stefanwalther/sense-extension-recipes